# XAML control layout in StackPanel

Tags: xaml

I have a lot of elements in my XAML code that i need to switch between visible and collapsed in my main code...

I have tried to create a parent of type `StackPanel` for all those elements. But now it messes up all the child element positions (it scatters them all over the place).

Is there any way to set that the parent does not control the position of the child and only controls the Visibility property... Or is there any other type of element used for parenting and grouping ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `StackPanel` control will size to its child elements. Use a `Grid` control instead, which will size to its parent control and the position of your elements should stay as they were before.